# Modify JSON and display in Kendo UI Grid

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-grid

Given this JSON:

```
{
"Header": {
    "NewNetworkServiceProvider": "NewNetworkServiceProvidera9ae97fe-e59a-4678-91ea-5a03c7d0f5cc",
    "PurchaseOrderNumber": "PurchaseOrderNumberdf932a47-1476-4a78-a9d0-de538ed8306b",
    "ConfirmedVersionString": "ConfirmedVersionString12e9d37c-f8dd-4251-bc55-7c83732b5629"
    }
}
```

}

I would like to turn it into:

```
[
  { "label": "NewNetworkerviceProvider", "value": "NewNetworkServiceProvider87cc6600-49c5-46fa-9fe7-d6f614645edb"},
  { "label": "PurchaseOrderNumber", "value": "PurchaseOrderNumber85475a1e-f22d-46f0-b437-9528b7564ab1" },
  { "label": "ConfirmedVersionString", "value": "VersionString2fa72562-dec5-4edd-9ba3-e2e2c563acb6" }
];
```

Then I can make that a data source in the Kendo UI Grid.

I just need a push in the right direction  to either transform that data into the format I need or is there a move advanced method to apply a schema template that will dynamically display the data in the way I need it to.

At the moment using that test data I can display it in the grid and it's awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate the property and use hasOwnProperty

```
var json = {
"Header": {
    "NewNetworkServiceProvider": "NewNetworkServiceProvidera9ae97fe-e59a-    4678-91ea-5a03c7d0f5cc",
    "PurchaseOrderNumber": "PurchaseOrderNumberdf932a47-1476-4a78-a9d0-    de538ed8306b",
    "ConfirmedVersionString": "ConfirmedVersionString12e9d37c-f8dd-4251-bc55-7c83732b5629"
    }
}

var result = []

for (var property in json.Header)
{
    if (json.Header.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                var obj = {label:"",value:""}
                obj.label = property ; 
                obj.value = json.Header[property];
                result.push(obj);
            }
}
```

you can stringify the js object by using JSON.stringify

Comment: thanks @kwan245, that is working.  I can edit it in the grid.

Can i use a similar approach to make it look the same as the original JSON using the edited data from the grid?